# I can't move x,y,z axes of my three.js sphere

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I am using Three.js and i have a problem,
i followed this video fhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUgWfqWZWmM and my problem begin at 48 minutes.
my mousemove event for moving on x,y and z axes is not working.[I found this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHpgr.png)
Sorry for bad my english. Hope your guys can help me

```
document.addEventListener('mousmeove', onDocumentMouseMove)

let mouseX = 0;
let mouseY = 0;

let targetX = 0;
let targetY = 0;

const windowX = window.innerWidth / 2;
const windowY = window.innerHeight / 2;

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

    mouseX = (event.clientX - windowX)
    mouseY = (event.clientY - windowY)  
}
 
const updateSphere = (event) => {
    sphere.position.y = window.scrollY * .001
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', updateSphere)

const clock = new THREE.Clock()

const tick = () =>
{
    targetX = mouseX * .001
    targetY = mouseY * .001

    const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime()

    // Update objects
    sphere.rotation.y = .5 * elapsedTime

    sphere.rotation.y += .5 * (targetX - sphere.rotation.y)
    sphere.rotation.x += .5 * (targetY - sphere.rotation.x)
    sphere.position.z += .5 * (targetY - sphere.rotation.x)

    // Update Orbital Controls
    // controls.update()

    // Render
    renderer.render(scene, camera)

    // Call tick again on the next frame
    window.requestAnimationFrame(tick)
}

tick()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the code itself works as expected. I suggest you use the following code as a template. It organized the app a bit different compared to your approach.

```js
let camera, scene, renderer;
let sphere;

let mouseX = 0;
let mouseY = 0;

let targetX = 0;
let targetY = 0;

const windowX = window.innerWidth / 2;
const windowY = window.innerHeight / 2;

const clock = new THREE.Clock()

init();
animate();

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10);
  camera.position.z = 4;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry();
  const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({
    flatShading: true
  });

  sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(sphere);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove);

}

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

  mouseX = (event.clientX - windowX);
  mouseY = (event.clientY - windowY);

}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  targetX = mouseX * 0.001;
  targetY = mouseY * 0.001;

  const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime()

  // Update objects
  sphere.rotation.y = 0.5 * elapsedTime;

  sphere.rotation.y += 0.5 * (targetX - sphere.rotation.y)
  sphere.rotation.x += 0.5 * (targetY - sphere.rotation.x)
  sphere.rotation.z += 0.5 * (targetY - sphere.rotation.x)

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.135.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you **copy-paste** the code you've provided in your question **from your code** itself or **from the tutorial** which you are following?
The reason why I'm asking it is because [this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHpgr.png) is different than the code in your question.
In your error message **the previous line is incomplete** and ends with the multiplication operator.

I assume that the **transpiler** interprets the following line initialising

```
const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime()
```

as being part of the previous incomplete line.

***In easier terms***:

In your question the code is like

```
targetY = mouseY * 0.001;

const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime()
```

while the code in the error message is

```
targetY = mouseY *

const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime()
```

Please check your code if the line preceding the alleged error is complete as it is in your question or incomplete as it is in the error message.

PS: Be consistent with the use of the semicolons terminating code lines. Sometime you use them sometimes you don't…not cool…!

PSII: I assume that you have found the solution by yourself. But please let the community know. Even if it's a simple error like I assume. That has happened to the best…!

**Always embrace the mistakes you do because they will make you a better coder…!**